# iDangerous Swiper gets out of sync after onSlideClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I have two Swipers on a page, which are linked and synchronized. Both are looped and show some 60 slides or so (length is dynamic). Both Swipers have pagination and it works fine on both a click on 'next' and 'previous' button (.swipePrev() and .swipeNext()).

The first Swiper is showing just one big image, the second one is a carousel with thumbnails (showing the active one, and two previous and two next slides). When I page on either one, the active index is updated and the active slide is centered in the small one, the big image is updated too.

I now want to add functionality to also update both sliders when I click on a slide in the carousel. I added the following code to the carousel:

```
onSlideClick: function() {
    accoPager.swipeTo(accoPager.clickedSlideIndex);
    accoSlider.swipeTo(accoPager.activeIndex);
}
```

This works fine when I click it once, but on a second click it doesn't work anymore.

Fun thing, after I use the regular pagers (the arrow buttons on either side), or I slide, the events work again. What seems to be happening is that the active index is not updated properly when I use .swipeTo(), but it is corrected when I use .swipeNext() or .swipePrevious().

The initialization of the Swipers is (big one first):

```
slider= $('#acco-slider-top').swiper({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    paginationClickable: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    loop: true,
    loopedSlides: 99,
    onTouchEnd: function () {
        pagerCarousel.swipeTo(slider.activeIndex);
    }
});

pagerCarousel = $('#pager-area .swiper-container').swiper({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    paginationClickable: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    offsetPxBefore: 144,
    loop: true,
    loopedSlides: 99,
    onTouchEnd: function () {
        slider.swipeTo(pagerCarousel.activeIndex);
    },
    onSlideClick: function() {
        pagerCarousel.swipeTo(pagerCarousel.clickedSlideIndex);
        slider.swipeTo(pagerCarousel.clickedSlideIndex);
    }
});
```

I tried setting the active index, but that doesn't work. When I alert anything in the onSlideClick event I found that the event is still linked to the Swiper, but it gets stopped somewhere in the swiper code.

Does anyone have any issues with this too and what's the best way to proceed? I think it has something to do with the params.onSlideClick _this.allowSlideClick toggles in the Swiper code, but I can't pinpoint what exactly.

EDIT: Not unimportantly, I'm using Swiper 2.4.2+

Answer (score 0):

This should work, hard to say where is the problem without looking at live example. Check this example and how it is done here, maybe it will be helpful http://goo.gl/Nc2M5P

Comment: I changed my code to look more like yours and then it indeed works. However, if I try to turn on the loop it all breaks again.

Is there a way to loop slides too, when using your example?